# Facing error (hadoop on windows 10)ExitCodeException exitCode=1: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, sqoop

I am facing error  "Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): required privilege is not held by the client." .

This is while running sqoop job for  import table from mysql to Hadoop.

I am using windows(win 10) setup with single cluster and node.
Sqoop is running on same machine. 
 Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please formulate this as a question.